# How can arrange my table of abbreviation from A to Z?

Tags: tables

I would be grateful if you could help me to arrange my table from A to Z Abbreviation, my code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\huge\sc\centering}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{List of Abbreviation}
\begin{longtable}{@{}|l|l|@{}}
\hline
\textbf{Abbreviation} & \textbf{Meaning}                                  \\ \hline
DG                    & Distributed Generation                            \\ \hline
EPRI                  & Electric Power Research Institute                 \\ \hline
CIGRE                 & International Councilon Large Electric Systems    \\ \hline
IEEE                  & Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers \\ \hline
IEA                   & International Energy Agency                       \\ \hline
DER                   & Distributed Energy Resource                       \\ \hline
BES                   & Bulk Electric System                              \\ \hline
MV                    & Medium Voltage                                    \\ \hline
LV                    & Low Voltage                                       \\ \hline
PV                    & Photovoltaic Systems                              \\ \hline
PVPP                  & PV Power Plants                                   \\ \hline
AC                    & Alternating Current                               \\ \hline
DC                    & Direct Current                                    \\ \hline
CT                    & Current Transforms                                \\ \hline
VT                    & Valtage Transforms                                \\ \hline
OR                    & Overcurrent Relay                                 \\ \hline
CTI                   & Coordinating Time Interval                        \\ \hline
MM                    & Minimum Meting                                    \\ \hline
TC                    & Total Clearing                                    \\ \hline
CSP                   & Concentrating Solar Power                         \\ \hline
SWH                   & Solar Water Heating                               \\ \hline
PCC                   & Point of Common Coupling                          \\ \hline
CB                    & Circuit Breaker                                   \\ \hline
DN                    & Distribution Network                              \\ \hline
CCT                   & Critical Clearing Time                            \\ \hline
DNOs                  & Distribution Network Operators                    \\ \hline
EPS                   & Electric Power Systems                            \\ \hline
FRT                   & Fault Ride Through                                \\ \hline
CSU                   & Current Sensing Unit                              \\ \hline
GTO                   & Gate Turn off Thyristor                           \\ \hline
OPF                   & Optimal Power Flow                                \\ \hline
PSO                   & Particle Swarm Optimization                       \\ \hline
GA                    & Genetic Algorithm                                 \\ \hline
RTU                   & Remote Thermal Units                              \\ \hline
RNC                   & Ring Network Cabinet                              \\ \hline
MS                    & Master Station                                    \\ \hline
FFT                   & Fast Fourier Transform                            \\ \hline
THD                   & Total Harmonic Distortion                         \\ \hline
FCL                   & Fault Current Limiters                            \\ \hline
SMES                  & Superconducting Magnetic Energy Storage           \\ \hline
IEDs                  & Intelligent Electronic Devices                    \\ \hline
SCADA                 & Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition          \\ \hline
LBPC                  & Local Backup Protection Center                    \\ \hline
SBPC                  & System Backup Protection Center                   \\ \hline
WPT                   & Wavelet Packet Transform                          \\ \hline
LG                    & Line-Ground                                       \\ \hline
LLG                   & Line- Line-Ground                                 \\ \hline
LLLG                  & Three Phase Fault                                 \\ \hline
MDL                   & Minimum Description Length                        \\ \hline
MMF                   & Mathematical Morphology Filters                   \\ \hline
CMS                   & Current Multiplier setting                        \\ \hline
TMS                   & Time Multiplier Setting                           \\ \hline
IP                    & Primary Relay                                     \\ \hline
IB                    & Backup Relay                                      \\ \hline
ETAP                  & Electrical Transient Analysis Program             \\ \hline
PS                    & Plug Setting                                      \\ \hline
CTR                   & Current Transformer Ratio                         \\ \hline
APS                   & Adaptive Protection Scheme                        \\ \hline
SCC                   & Short Circuit Current                             \\ \hline
PMS                   & Plug Multiplying Setting                          \\ \hline
FRB                   & Fuzzy Rule Base                                   \\ \hline
DOCRs                 & Directional Over-Current Relays                   \\ \hline
MINLP                 & Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming              \\ \hline
MILP                  & Mixed Integer Linear Programming                  \\ \hline
LP                    & Linear Programming                                \\ \hline
MOPSO                 & Multi-Objective Particle Swarm Optimization       \\ \hline
FDMT                  & Fuzzy Decision Making Tool                        \\ \hline
OFs                   & Objective Functions                               \\ \hline
DT                    & Duration Time                                     \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
\newpage
```

Comment: Why don't you use a package like glossaries, which would do this for you?

Comment: I don't any idea about glossaries package, could you explain it please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

This is too long for a comment. If inappropriate, I will delete this answer afterwards.

Just hope this helps.

```
AC                    & Alternating Current                               \\ \hline
APS                   & Adaptive Protection Scheme                        \\ \hline
BES                   & Bulk Electric System                              \\ \hline
CB                    & Circuit Breaker                                   \\ \hline
CCT                   & Critical Clearing Time                            \\ \hline
CIGRE                 & International Councilon Large Electric Systems    \\ \hline
CMS                   & Current Multiplier setting                        \\ \hline
CSP                   & Concentrating Solar Power                         \\ \hline
CSU                   & Current Sensing Unit                              \\ \hline
CT                    & Current Transforms                                \\ \hline
CTI                   & Coordinating Time Interval                        \\ \hline
CTR                   & Current Transformer Ratio                         \\ \hline
DC                    & Direct Current                                    \\ \hline
DER                   & Distributed Energy Resource                       \\ \hline
DG                    & Distributed Generation                            \\ \hline
DN                    & Distribution Network                              \\ \hline
DNOs                  & Distribution Network Operators                    \\ \hline
DOCRs                 & Directional Over-Current Relays                   \\ \hline
DT                    & Duration Time                                     \\ \hline
EPRI                  & Electric Power Research Institute                 \\ \hline
EPS                   & Electric Power Systems                            \\ \hline
ETAP                  & Electrical Transient Analysis Program             \\ \hline
FCL                   & Fault Current Limiters                            \\ \hline
FDMT                  & Fuzzy Decision Making Tool                        \\ \hline
FFT                   & Fast Fourier Transform                            \\ \hline
FRB                   & Fuzzy Rule Base                                   \\ \hline
FRT                   & Fault Ride Through                                \\ \hline
GA                    & Genetic Algorithm                                 \\ \hline
GTO                   & Gate Turn off Thyristor                           \\ \hline
IB                    & Backup Relay                                      \\ \hline
IEA                   & International Energy Agency                       \\ \hline
IEDs                  & Intelligent Electronic Devices                    \\ \hline
IEEE                  & Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers \\ \hline
IP                    & Primary Relay                                     \\ \hline
LBPC                  & Local Backup Protection Center                    \\ \hline
LG                    & Line-Ground                                       \\ \hline
LLG                   & Line- Line-Ground                                 \\ \hline
LLLG                  & Three Phase Fault                                 \\ \hline
LP                    & Linear Programming                                \\ \hline
LV                    & Low Voltage                                       \\ \hline
MDL                   & Minimum Description Length                        \\ \hline
MILP                  & Mixed Integer Linear Programming                  \\ \hline
MINLP                 & Mixed Integer Non-linear Programming              \\ \hline
MM                    & Minimum Meting                                    \\ \hline
MMF                   & Mathematical Morphology Filters                   \\ \hline
MOPSO                 & Multi-Objective Particle Swarm Optimization       \\ \hline
MS                    & Master Station                                    \\ \hline
MV                    & Medium Voltage                                    \\ \hline
OFs                   & Objective Functions                               \\ \hline
OPF                   & Optimal Power Flow                                \\ \hline
OR                    & Overcurrent Relay                                 \\ \hline
PCC                   & Point of Common Coupling                          \\ \hline
PMS                   & Plug Multiplying Setting                          \\ \hline
PS                    & Plug Setting                                      \\ \hline
PSO                   & Particle Swarm Optimization                       \\ \hline
PV                    & Photovoltaic Systems                              \\ \hline
PVPP                  & PV Power Plants                                   \\ \hline
RNC                   & Ring Network Cabinet                              \\ \hline
RTU                   & Remote Thermal Units                              \\ \hline
SBPC                  & System Backup Protection Center                   \\ \hline
SCADA                 & Supervisory Control and Data Acquisition          \\ \hline
SCC                   & Short Circuit Current                             \\ \hline
SMES                  & Superconducting Magnetic Energy Storage           \\ \hline
SWH                   & Solar Water Heating                               \\ \hline
TC                    & Total Clearing                                    \\ \hline
THD                   & Total Harmonic Distortion                         \\ \hline
TMS                   & Time Multiplier Setting                           \\ \hline
VT                    & Valtage Transforms                                \\ \hline
WPT                   & Wavelet Packet Transform                          \\ \hline
```

Comment: Question is the table is alphabetically, but how did you do it? Most interesting is is it possible to do this automatically.

Comment: I use emacs, and this is a simple `sort-regexp-fields` followed by inputting ^.*$ for sorting lines and then \& to use the whole match as the key. I think there is a way to do this in plain tex macros. I know this is the wrong site to post about emacs, but just trying to help, somehow.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by emacs? how can arrange by coding